# Display Size/Width Adjustment

Tags: mathjax

I was wandering if there is a way to adjust width of the math mathjax renders. Some math expression I have are longer and won't fit in a box I have created. Is there a way to squeeze it and make it fit maybe by changing the size or width? I have tried using line breaks but that isn't what I want. An example would be a mathjax like this:

```
2x+3+4 - /intcos(x) dx   


234567897+sin(2x)+34567890987654.
```

Displaying the last line would be a problem because it won't fit in the box. It overflows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use `\small` or `\scriptsize` or `\Tiny` (non-standard) or `\tiny` within the mathematics to make it appear in a smaller size.

Alternatively, you could put a `<span style="font-size:70%">...</span>` around the mathematics to get the math to be scaled to whatever size you need.  E.g.,

```
<span style="font-size:70%">\(234567897+sin(2x)+34567890987654\)</span>
```

Note that the math delimiters must be inside the `<span>`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the Mathjax config. By this, I mean making it the font-size change dynamically. I have been looking and I haven't found any solution.

Comment: No, there is no configuration to tell MathJax to adjust the size to fit the space available.  But there is a technique discussed in the [MathJax user's forum](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mathjax-users/ems8PNage-0/discussion) that shows how you can dynamically change the scaling yourself.  it could be adapted to go through multiple equations to set their size, for example.

Comment: I assume you mean "*Where* does `\small` go?"  You put it at the beginning of the equation that you want to be smaller.  E.g., `\(\small E=mc^2\)`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that doesn't require adding elements or css code:

```
// resize all LaTeX Display elements to they fit in on screen
function cvonk_ResizeMathJax() {
    jQuery('.MathJax_Display').each(function(ii, obj) {
        var latex = obj.children[0];
        var w = latex.offsetWidth;
        var h = latex.offsetHeight;    
        var W = obj.offsetWidth;
        if (w > W) {
            obj.style.fontSize = 95 * W / w + "%";
        }
    });
}
window.MathJax = {
    AuthorInit: function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("Begin", function() {
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
        cvonk_ResizeMathJax();
        });
    });
    },
    jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS", "output/NativeMML"],
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"]
};
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    cvonk_ResizeMathJax();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mathjax-users/ems8PNage-0/discussion) linked to above:

```
function changeSize(button) {
    var myeqn = document.getElementById('myeqn');
    myeqn.style.fontSize = button.textContent;
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(
    ['Rerender', MathJax.Hub, 'myeqn'],

    function () {
        document.getElementById('mylabel').innerHTML =
            'width: ' + myeqn.offsetWidth + ", height: " + myeqn.offsetHeight;
    });
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/nLyraL1f/ or http://jsfiddle.net/s2bjepk6/.

This is also nice because it gets the width and height of the rendered latex, useful for things like rendering it as an element positioned over a canvas since you can draw things on the canvas around it.